# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've been trying to go over all the answers to this already but have failed to implement them to my code. I understand what happens is that before I rendered the page with the error response, another response had been sent to the user. On the other hand, I have no idea how to fix this.

Here is how I throw an error in my script:

```
if (!player) {
      next(new HttpError(404, "Player not found")); // HttpError(status, message)
    }
```

To send this error to the user I use method sendHttpError.js which is this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){

    res.sendHttpError = function(error){
        if(res.req.headers['x-requested-with'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'){
            res.json(error);
        }else {
            res.render("error", {error: error});
        }
    };
    next();
};
```

And this is a little bit enhanced express error-handler:

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {

    if(typeof err == 'number'){
      err = new HttpError(err);
    }

    if(err instanceof HttpError){
      res.sendHttpError(err);
    } else{
      if(app.get('env') == 'development'){
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        });
      } else {
        log.error(err);
        err = new HttpError(500);
        res.sendHttpError(err);
      }
    }
  });
```

I am a bit new to node and js coming from C++ so it's a bit hard to grab onto this confusing event-oriented programming :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Likely the problem lies here:

```
if (!player) {
  next(new HttpError(404, "Player not found")); // HttpError(status, message)
}
```

Put a return in front of the next() call.

Without the return the next function will be called, but the route handler will continue to execute as well.  You might have a handler that looks something like this:

```
app.get('/foo', function(req, res, next){
    if (!player) 
      next(new HttpError(404, "Player not found")); // HttpError(status, message)

     res.send({res:'ok'});

});
```

The next function is called and your error handler. Perhaps it writes a response to the client. The normal res.send is then called in your handler and you get the "Can't set handler error".

More likely the res.send function gets called first and the error will be raised in your express error-handler.